# Export application oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Trying to create a script to export my apex application. Using sqlcl, you can do
`apex export 100`. Is there a way to do this using plain sql or pl/sql which are the ones that the Script Editor in Oracle Apex accepts?

Comment: If you're already logged into the APEX UI, can you use the built-in export feature? Scripting should be done from the OS command-line, not from within a browser UI.

Comment: I'm trying to automate deploying my application through the use of scripts. I might try to do it using a batch script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the *script* part, but not (PL/)SQL - create an operating system **batch script**. I'm on MS Windows, here's an example of what you might do:

```
REM Go to UTILITIES directory of your Apex installation directory
D:
cd D:\apex_4.2_instalacija\utilities

REM List of all applications you'll be exporting

REM Predmeti
java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db db_orcl:1521:orcl  -user pred   -password urb9xyz  -applicationid 126
REM Naljepnice
java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db db_orcl:1521:orcl  -user naljep -password stiwzf   -applicationid 139
REM                                                 -----------------------------
REM                                                 Oracle schema username/password, 
REM                                                 not Apex developer's or workspace or ...

REM Today's date in YYYY_MM_DD format
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyy_mm_dd=%%l_%%k_%%j

REM ZIP filename: APEX_YYYY_MM_DD.ZIP
set ime_zipa=apex_%yyyy_mm_dd%.zip

REM ZIP all exported applications (i.e. .SQL files)
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -tzip %ime_zipa% D:\apex_backup\f*.sql

REM Keep the ZIP, delete SQL files
del f*.sql
```

That's contents of my `my_apex_export.bat` file. Schedule it using "Task Scheduler"; I'm running it every day at 21:00 o'clock and keep daily exports since March 2012.

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Littlefoot
Is there a utility for Importing too? Like oracle.apex.APEXImport?

Comment: @Oguen, there are 2 ways of doing it: import application using GUI (Apex import wizard), or execute exported .SQL script in SQL*Plus (or any similar tool). More info in documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_app_inst.htm#AEAPI557)

Comment: thank you, 
it'll be a little off-topic but how do you see which page/app imported by whom? there must be an APEX View for this but I couldn't find.

Comment: You're welcome, @Oguen. I don't know how to find that info, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the answer by Littlefoot works perfect, but just wanted to add that this can also be achieved in sqlcl natively. Using the `SCRIPT` command in sqlcl you can invoke a script written in nashhorn javascript code. Search google for "sqlcl scripting" for a ton of examples.